# Building cdk modal - ngOnInit is not triggered and no data is passed

Tags: angular, angular-cdk

I'm trying to build `modals` library  that is dependent only on `CDK`.
Modal is opened with service and I pass `entryComponent` to render it in modal.

Here is sample: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ofzpks?file=src%2Fapp%2Fmodal.component.ts

In modal itself I'm creating component with factory:

```
const compRef = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory<any>(this.modalContentComponent);
const componentRef = this.modalContainer.createComponent(compRef);
```

I have two problems:

1. I have to trigger `componentRef.instance.ngOnInit();` manually
2. I pass some data to that component: `componentRef.instance.name = this.data.name;` but component never renders it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `modal.component.ts`, use `ngOnInit` instead of `ngAfterViewInit`:

```
ngOnInit() {
  const compRef = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory<any>(this.modalContentComponent);
  const componentRef = this.modalContainer.createComponent(compRef);
  componentRef.instance.name = this.data.name;
}
```

[Updated StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gpvykk)

---

Doing it this way means that [`ngDoCheck`](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks#lifecycle-sequence) will run and detect the changes for you since `ngDoCheck` runs directly after `ngOnInit`.

Comment: Great - thanks very much. I thought I have to do it then when view will be inited.

Comment: Nice one, that's awesome!